# How to pass variable as a parameter in SQL in python

Tags: python, sql, parameters

Question: I want to use either variable x as a parameter for where condition in SQL query. Also, can I use data frame as a parameter for where condition in SQL in python
Query:

```
x= ('610094437','4738521095','4738671217')
cur = conn.cursor()
sql = "select QUOTE_OBJECT_ID,OPTY_NUMBER from dmadm.cq_ccw_all_deal Where QUOTE_OBJECT_ID in ?"
cur.execute(sql,(x))
row=cur.fetchall()
print(row)
```

Comment: Query can't get tuple with 3 values as single element for `IN`. You may need to put values directly in SQL using `f-string`. OR you have to generate query with `IN (?,?,?)` and later use `execute(sql, x)`

Comment: [How can I write an SQL IN query with a Python tuple?](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-can-I-write-an-SQL-IN-query-with-a-Python-tuple)